# How to show the latest images that is uploaded in the subdirectory?

Tags: php

I wanted to upload recent images (Basically Scrteenshot) uploaded in the sub directory. The images are in this format "Screenshot from 2018-10-03 13-10-45.png" . I am using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847955/php-display-most-recent-images-from-directory) as a reference. But if you see my [result](https://lifetree.co.in/img/) , what i am getting is the basically the images are ordering itself in descending order. I am new to php. I am unable to tweak the code. Basically I want the images in ascending order.

This is my code.This one is giving the descending order. I wanted to show them in ascending order. 
*

```
$images = glob('*.{gif,png,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE); //formats to look for

$num_of_files = 4; //number of images to display

foreach($images as $image)
{
     $num_of_files--;

     if($num_of_files > -1) //this made me laugh when I wrote it
       echo "<b>".$image."</b><br>Created on ".date('D, d M y H:i:s', filemtime($image)) ."<br><img src="."'".$image."'"."><br><br>" ; //display images
     else
       break;
}
```

?>*

Answer (score 0):

Just try to reverse your result array:

```
array_reverse ( $result );
```

Then you should get an ascending order.

Comment: Where shall i put this line? Inside the loop?

Comment: No try after sort($list); add array_reverse ( $list );

Comment: Hey ivion , I have updated my post. I added my code. There is no array.

Comment: try the following. add as second line sort($images); after that array_reverse($images);

Comment: No effect.  I think in need to do somehting with the if loop

Comment: Perhaps on line to much. try to Remove the reverse_array() line